# How do I write <8e>?

Tags: substitute

I extracted the text from a pdf which I need to edit further in vim. It contains quite a few diacritical combinations, some of them apparently got converted to control characters by `pdftotext`. It seems most of which I already found, but <8e> remains.

Answer (score 5):

Vim provides a mechanism for entering arbitrary characters, which should work across all operating systems. See `:help i_CTRL-V_digit`.

To enter `<8e>`, you can type the following:

<kbd>Ctrl-V</kbd><kbd>x</kbd><kbd>8</kbd><kbd>e</kbd>

Note that if you have <kbd>Ctrl-V</kbd>mapped to perform another operation (such as, on Windows, paste, via `mswin.vim`) then in GUI Vim you can use <kbd>Ctrl-Q</kbd> instead.

Answer (score 0):

It seems I found my answer already myself, noting it down here for future reference: `<8e>`, highlighted in blue, is a unicode number, which can be entered in a standard Ubuntu setup via something like `<ctrl><shift>u008e<enter>`.